# Using the TRY_CONVERT function to assign the result to a declared variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have a client which sends us information to a staging table on our SQL database, the problem is that the source system sending the information is only capable of sending the value as a VARCHAR and I am trying to convert this into a FLOAT perform a small calculation, convert it back to VARCHAR and return the information to the source system.

I tried using the TRY_CONVERT() SQL built in function, but it would appear that you cannot assign the result set to a declared variable.

```
DECLARE @FloatValue float

SELECT @FloatValue = (TRY_CONVERT(float, '123.456') AS [varchar to float])
```

I have tried a normal convert `convert(float, [FIELDVALUE])`, but I keep getting the error unable to convert data type varchar to float. Any suggestions please? Below is a watered down version of the select statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #Samples
    (
        Id int
        ,Result varchar(255)
        ,Units varchar(50)
    )

INSERT INTO #Samples
SELECT 
    [ID] as [Id]
    ,CASE [UNITS]
        WHEN '%' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), (CONVERT(FLOAT, [RESULT])/100))
        ELSE [RESULT]
    END AS [Result]
    /**/
    ,[UNITS] as [Units]
FROM C_MES_STAGING 
WHERE [UNITS] = '%'

SELECT * FROM #Samples
DROP TABLE #Samples
```

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT()` does the exact same thing as `CONVERT`, except it returns `NULL` in the event of an error. To solve the error you probably have to replace the `.` with a `,`.

Comment: what happens with the decimal point? There is no thousand separator.

Comment: Also, you don't need the alias.

Comment: I know it's overkill, still not solving the problem ;)

Comment: What's the error when TRY_CONVERT is used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below options and please let us know if you get any issues.

```
--Assigning value to a Variable
DECLARE @FloatValue float

SELECT  @FloatValue = TRY_CONVERT(float, '123.456')
SELECT @FloatValue

--Checking if the value ISNUMERIC and then CASTING
SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC('123.456') WHEN 1 THEN CAST('123.456' AS float) ELSE null END
```

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Comment: @HABO really a good information on the `IsNumeric()`, thak you so much for sharing this info.